# Почему сгенерированный HTML элемент не получает событие

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос всего один, почему созданный SPAN НЕ получает событие.**

```
    const title = document.querySelector('.title');
// const h1 = document.querySelector('.h1');
const span = document.querySelectorAll('.span');


const str = 'Slovo'
const anim = [...str];




anim.forEach(e => {
    title.innerHTML += `<span class="span">${e}</span>`
});

span.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        console.log('yes');
        e.classList.toggle('span__active');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто и логично: потому что событие навешивается **до** создания элемента и оно о нём ничего не знает. Поэтому надо на вновь созданный элемент навешивать обработчик. Либо выключать обработчик у всех и включать на все заново (что иногда проще). Либо воспользоваться делегированием события, т.е. когда событие навешивается на какого-либо родителя, который никогда не изменяется

**[Подробнее о делегировании](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)**

Comment: Благодарю, разобрался!

Comment: _потому что событие навешивается до создания элемента_ - в данном случае это неверно. В приведенном коде - в момент навешивания все элементы уже есть в DOM

Answer (score 2):

Потому что [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает не живую коллекцию.

Вместо этого можно воспользоваться [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

```js
const span = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

const str = 'Slovo'
const anim = [...str];

anim.forEach(e => {
  title.innerHTML += `<span class="span">${e}</span>`
});

for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
  const e = span[i];
  e.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    console.log('yes');
    e.classList.toggle('span__active');
  })
}
```

```css
.span__active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, это тоже решает мою дилемму